# Why am i getting Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to angular and i am trying to replace some scope data structure with a factory but the dependency injection is causing an issue. Help please

https://jsfiddle.net/bennacer860/k8js1o4m/1/

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
  .factory('posts', [function() {
    var o = {
      posts: []
    };
    return o;
  }]);


angular.module('flapperNews', [])
  .service('myService', function() { /* ... */ })
  .controller('MyController', ['myService', function(myService) {
    // Do something with myService
    console.log("test");
  }]);


angular.module('flapperNews', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts) {
    $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
    // $scope.posts = [
    //   {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
    //   {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
    //   {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
    //   {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
    //   {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
    // ];
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;

    $scope.addPost = function() {
      if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
        return;
      }
      $scope.posts.push({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link,
        upvotes: 0
      });
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.link = '';
    };

    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
      post.upvotes += 1;
    };
  }]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eliminate the `[]` in each `angular.module('flapperNews', [])` after the first.

Passing an argument there tells angular to create a new instance of your module and therefore destroys any previous instances.